# Can I develop Custom Camera in android ?

Tags: android

I want to open **camera with in my own design** and **I don't want to use inbuilt camera** in android. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use the camera in your own apps:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html